# Problem using /dev/tty1 as a slave device via USB>TTL (RPiv2-B)

Tags: usb, serial

I'm trying to run a process on my RPi that acts as a SerialPort echo: that is, simply log to a file every character it receives.

My RPi is connected to my Mac (or PC) by a USB>TTL cable. I confirmed the cable works by logging into the console via UART0, by using `screen /dev/cu.usbserial` on my Mac.

The OS is Raspbian Jessie and I have disabled serial login using `raspi-config` and removed the console arguments from `/boot/cmdline.txt`. This works since I can no longer log in via `screen` or `putty`.

I figured before writing the Python/Perl/Node code to act as the echo, I'd test out the connection first using `screen`.

The problem is, I assumed I could simply run `screen /dev/tty1 9600` on my RPi, and then run `screen /dev/cu.usbserial 9600` on my Mac (or COMx/9600 on PuTTY on my PC) and then both terminals would just echo to each other.

Both instances of `screen` start (the ports are open), but neither one is echoing to the other.

What am I missing in terms of configuration on the PI, or misunderstanding about serial/UART communication?

Thanks in advance,
PT

SOLUTION: Milliways and goldilocks pointed out that `/dev/tty1` is a terminal. Once that was cleared up I saw that `serial0` is a link to `ttyAMA0`. However, neither of those worked. I had to go into `/boot/config.txt` and fix this "enable_uart=0" to "enable_uart=1". Now `screen` to `screen` works with `/dev/serial0`.

Comment: `/dev/tty1` is a console, not a serial port

Comment: @Milliways /dev/facepalm. Thanks. Is there a /dev/* device attached to UART0?

Comment: try `dev/serial0` depends on which OS and which Pi. The Foundation has been fiddling with firmware, and disabling serial by default on some e.g. Pi3

Comment: @Milliways I tried serial0 and ttyAMA0 (also tried using a perl Device::SerialPort object instead of ```screen```. No luck. Thanks tho. If you can think of anything else I'm all ears.

Comment: If `dev/serial0` exists then your problem is probably the connections. I have never used `screen` on the Pi - it doesn't seem to exist on my Pi.

Comment: @milliways i found that i had to set "enable_uart=1" in config.txt. Not sure why that was off.

Comment: See [How-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)
The Foundation seems to have decided (without telling anyone) to disable serial in kernel 4.4.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is on the Pi `/dev/tty1` isn't a UART anything.

TTY is a generic term for a text based terminal interface.  A serial console is a sort of subcategory of that, but not all ttys are serial consoles. The OS will normally run 6 such [virtual terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) ("virtual" by the fact that they aren't actually hardware artifacts) which you can access *locally* using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F-[1-6]</kbd>.  You can run `screen` within such a terminal, because `screen` isn't exclusively for the purpose of making remote serial connections.

On the pi, both `/dev/tty1` and a UART interface (such as `/dev/ttyAMA0`) are specified in `cmdline.txt` for use as outputs for console messages from the kernel, which create some confusion.  The UART allows for the messages to be read via a serial connection; `tty1` means they will also show up on the primary hardware display.

Comment: Thanks! Milliways above caught that too. I tried using ttyAMA0 and serial0 but I still wasn't arriving at the expected behavior. Is my idea of using screen<>screen sound to begin with? Wondering if that my be my problem.

Comment: Note that the connection / cables are good because I can re-enable console login and it works fine.

Comment: I add to set "enable_uart=1" in config.txt. Works now (with /dev/serial0)

Comment: :) Was just about to mention `serial0` -- it's now being used as a symbolic link since the Pi 3's setup complicated all this.